# Java save JavaObjects in sql database

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to save a Java Object in my SQL Database but im getting an errory I cannot solve ...

```
stat.executeUpdate("CREATE Table users( id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,name char(50), pw char(50), messages LONGBLOB, profile LONGBLOB )");
```

.
.
.

```
public static void registerNewUser(String name , String pw , Profile profile){PreparedStatement ps=null;


        ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into users(name,pw,profile) VALUES(?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, pw);
        ps.setObject(3, (Object)profile);
        ps.executeUpdate();}
```

and finally it says

```
SQL Exception : Unknown SQL Type for PreparedStatement.setObject (SQL Type=1111
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setObject(Unknown Source)
```

Hope anybody can help me :D
Thx in advance

ps the profile class

```
public class Profile implements Serializable{
private String name;
private int idNumber;
private byte[] picture;
private String password;

public Profile(String n, int i, byte[] p, String pw) {
    this.name = n;
    this.idNumber = i;
    this.picture = p;
    this.password = pw;
}

public String getProfileName(){
    return this.name;
}
public int getIDNumber(){
    return this.idNumber;
}
public byte[] getProfilePicture(){
    return this.picture;
}
public String getPassword(){
    return this.password;
}

public void setIDNumber(int number){
    this.idNumber = number;
}
```

}

Fixed by just using  ps.setBytes(3,byte[]);

Comment: You can't just store random Java objects. What type is `profile`? You might need to serialize it some other format.

Comment: It's just a selfmade Java class which implements Serializable

Comment: Persisting serialized Java object in a database is generally a bad idea. I would recommend that you use blob column to store the picture and forget about serializing. Also, column called password sounds like a potential security risk - use hash instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `st.setBinaryStream(byte[])` instead of `st.setObject()` to save profile stream.

Comment: sorry just gives me another error ...[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.1.70-community]SQLBindParameter not used for all parameters
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) and [UserType](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-types). Do not let you scare off by it. Once you learn it you can do all those things with ease.

If you still want to go for jdbc use the following. Create a new ObjectOutputStream using an ArrayOutputStream. Now write your serializable object directly to the ObjectOutputStream and close it. Now use the underlying ArrayOutputStream to get the byte [] array representation of those data and just give the JDBC statement this byte array as value for your bLOB.

This should solve your problem. Actually this can be extracted to an utility class and used everywhere where you try to store serialized information.

Comment: If you need further guidance, just give me a comment, I will update the answer if needed.

Comment: already tried that as the answere above you suggested :D unfortunately this soultion throws [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.1.70-community]SQLBindParameter not used for all parameters at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source) for whartever reason